# Does IQOS/HEETS emits CO?

Tags: smoking, pulmonology

I am researching the safety of IQOS (THS2.2) for heat-not-burn cigarettes (HEETS).

I am particularly interested in appraising the impact of IQOS/HEETS on CO emission and inhalation.

Is there evidence of this?